# Return index on selection of bootstrap nav tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement

I want to make a check on nav tabs. If current tab for example `$('.nav-tabs li:eq(3) a.active')` is active then `alert("3");` if tab no 4 then `alert("4");`. Any help would be nice.

my try

```
if($('.nav-tabs li:eq(3) a.active'))
{
  alert("3");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bootstrap (I assume you're using v3) has event callbacks that you may employ:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

You could do what you're asking for like this:

```
alert( $(e.target).closest('li').index() + 1 );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/aHXm4/

---

In response to your comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/aHXm4/2

```
if ($(e.target).closest('li').index() + 1 == 3) {
    var save = "jack";
    alert(save);
}
```

Comment: I had to check tab name so I used if ($(e.target).closest('li').text() == 'tabName') {....}